# entering data and displaying entered data using python

Tags: python, apache

I am newbie to python , I am trying to write a program in which i can print the entered data .

here is the program which I tried.

```
#!"C:\python34\python.exe"

import sys

print("Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8")
print()
firststring = "bill"
secondstring = "cows"
thridstring = "abcdef"
name = input('Enter your name : ')
print ("Hi %s, Let us be friends!" % name)
```

The output of this program is only :  "Enter your name : "
I cannot enter anything from my keyboard. I am running this program using apache in localhost like http://localhost:804/cgi-bin/ex7.py
Can anyone plz help me to print the user entered data. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That will only work if you run the program from the command line.

You are trying to run it as a web application, and those are very different.

HTTP is a request-response based protocol.
You send a request to the server, the server runs some code (the code you posed in this case), the server sends you the response.

`input` reads from the stdin so it won't work in this case.

What you need to do is to make a HTML form that the user submits, you read that form using the cgi module for python and then send an answer with the name in it.

It's really hard to explain this in detail because there are so many things to say.

Read more about HTTP, CGI, server-side code and python and you'll be fine.

Comment: Thank for information .Can you plz suggest some of the database libraries which can be used in web application, to store the data.

Comment: If you are going to keep using python you should use a framework like cherrypy or django. For the database look into the sqlalchemy ORM.